# How to place logo image , phone, location above navbar in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, class, bootstrap-4, navigation

I am new to Bootstrap: I want to place logo image, location image with address, phone number with text above the navigation. Logo details should be centered.
What I have tried:

```
    <header >
            
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 50%;" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    <img class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 5%" src="images/header-address.png" alt="logo">
                 <span class="span-text">1234 Abcd Efg  <br> HI jk Lm,123466 </span> 
                 <img class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 5%;" src="images/header-phone.png" alt="logo">
                <span class="span_text">(123) 456 7890 <br> Call Us </span> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>  
            </header>
        
        <section >
            <div class="container mx-auto">
                <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
     <div class="container-fluid">    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>     
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The alignment of the logo, location, and phone number is not achieved.
How to fix this?

Comment: Try align the items using table.

Comment: @TheBetweener How ? Is it possible in bootstrap. I want a responsive design

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Comment: Centered how? Vertically(`|`) or horizontally(`-`)?

Comment: I don't know for sure if it's responsive or not but you can align using the table.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Horizontally(-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto;` for `.col-md-6`

```
.col-md-6 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and if you want to also center the navigation items then add this:

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

### Top Phone number... centered:

[image: First One]

---

### Nav Items centered:

[image: Second image]

---

### Both centered with text-align

[image: Third image]

Comment: Navigation is working but location and phone text is not aligning properly

Comment: @Binsha updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: @Binsha which one do you want (the images)